# How to update an XML node with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

How do we update the a node name with a new value using LINQ?

```
<test xmlns="http://www.mydomain.com/test/xyz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
  <Ribbon1>test</Ribbon1>
  <Ribbon2>test</Ribbon2>
</test>
```

I was trying as below:

```
var query = from lst in XElement.Load(fileLoc).Elements(ns + "Ribbon1")
            select lst.FirstNode ;
```

The below code is working now:

```
XNamespace ns = @"http://www.mydomain.com/test/xyz";
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(fileLoc);
foreach (XElement descendant in xElement.Descendants(ns + "Ribbon1"))
    descendant.Value = "Borra";
xElement.Save(fileLoc);
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code use `Elemnts` and that only looks at the given level. To find something at an arbitrary level:

```
//XElement.Load(fileLoc).Elements(ns + "Ribbon1")
XElement.Load(fileLoc).Descendants(ns + "Ribbon1")
```

or to adhere to the structure:

```
XElement.Load(fileLoc).Element(ns + "test").Elements(ns + "Ribbon1")
```

be careful about  Element() and Elements()

Comment: foreach (var descendant in XElement.Load(fileLoc).Descendants("Ribbon1"))
            {
                descendant.Value = "Borra";

            }

 But it is not working

Comment: Does the Accept means you found the answer? You can also post a self answer with the Update. I don't have much time.

Answer (score 1):

```
 XNamespace ns = @"http://www.mydomain.com/test/xyz";
    XElement xElement = XElement.Load(fileLoc);
    foreach (XElement descendant in xElement.Descendants(ns + "Ribbon1"))
        descendant.Value = "Borra";
    xElement.Save(fileLoc);
```